Can't use MSAL on Android to access IIS services registered with Azure App Proxy
We registered the IIS service with Azure App Proxy.
Register that service in Mobile to get an Access Token with MSAL and request a soap with Authorization: Bearer  in the header.
The MSAL responds with the token as expected.
However, when you call the service with the token in the header, it responds with the MS Login page.
This is the same as using Postman, which returns the MS Login page.
We used the MSAL below.
https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-android
Postman
Access Token
After getting the Access Token using MSAL, we included it in the header and made a Soap call.
However, the MS login page was responded.
24.12.10 edited
mSingleAccountApp.getCurrentAccountAsync(new ISingleAccountPublicClientApplication.CurrentAccountCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onAccountLoaded(@Nullable IAccount activeAccount) {
                if (activeAccount == null) {
                    final SignInParameters signInParameters = SignInParameters.builder()
                            .withActivity(getActivity())
                            .withCallback(getAuthInteractiveCallback())
                            .withScopes(Arrays.asList(scopes))
                            .withLoginHint(pwdMailAdder)
                            .build();

                    mSingleAccountApp.signIn(signInParameters);
                }
                else {
                    mAccount = activeAccount;
                }
            }


and callback is below
private AuthenticationCallback getAuthInteractiveCallback() {
        return new AuthenticationCallback() {

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(IAuthenticationResult authenticationResult) { ...}



How did you generate the token? Can you paste the screenshot or parameters of generating token?

mApplicationIdentifier with value null/null doesn't look right; how about the broker? The question is generally a little too abstract to properly understand it.

@Rukmini I added the code please check it ..

@MartinZeitler Let us know what you need clarification on and we'll fix it.

This might be a misconception:

The MSAL responds with the token as expected.

You're acquiring an access-token for an application, but the application-identifier is "null/null".
When the access-token has property value mApplicationIdentifier = "null/null",
the authorities might not be configured properly or the broker might not work.
I'd assume that the access-token is not being requested with the proper AcquireTokenParameters or AcquireTokenSilentParameters; and that mApplicationIdentifier needs to have a matching application-identifier String value (unless it is not supposed to be "null/null" in that mode).

SingleAccountPublicClientApplication

msal/src/main/res/raw/msal_default_config.json

.default scope


SSO through brokered authentication

Exercise: Sign in users with MSAL



Look ...
<string name="broker_helper_package">Package name to enter when registering app</string>
The redirect_uri is not always https:// but may be msauth://.
